# get kendo grid filters to post with a button using KendoGridBinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-csv, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui grid and would like there to be an export button so that when they export to a CSV they could have the same filtering that is on the grid shown.

I would like the post to accept the KendoGridRequest much like the

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Grid(KendoGridRequest request)
    {
        var employees = GetEmployees();
        var grid = new KendoGrid<Employee>(request, employees);
        return Json(grid);
    }
```

I would like to add an **Export** button that would use the same filters in the post so 
the **Export** action could also accept the KendoGridRequest and would return a CSV file

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Export(KendoGridRequest request)
    {
        var employees = GetEmployees();
        var grid = new KendoGrid<Employee>(request, employees);
        return ToCsv(grid);
    }
```

the KendoGridRequest class comes from the [KendoGridBinder](http://github.com/rwhitmire/KendoGridBinder) project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can find all the items (needed to create an KendoGridRequest object) contained in the dataSource field exposed by the object of the Grid and send them when posting your data to the Export action method.

i.e.

```
   var dataSource = $('#yourGridID').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
    var page = dataSource._page;
    var skip = dataSource._skip;
    var take = dataSource._take;
    //etc.
```

Comment: this is great, I can get to the datasource._filter and all the filter stuff for this request. Is there a way to package and send easy so the controller can read the KendoGridRequest? so I dont have to say ds._filter[0].value etc.......

Comment: Is there a way to package and send easy so the controller can read the KendoGridRequest?